# How to edit legend description in ggplot without getting a second legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I had been trying to include a legend in my plot that shows the name of the months next to the line with its respective colour and shape but I can't figure it out.

I have tried using scale_color_hue() but I got two different legends

```
isop_temp <-  ggplot(bio_all_data, aes(t_2m, isop)) +
              geom_jitter(aes(shape = month, colour = month, fill = month)) +
              geom_smooth(aes(group = month, colour = month), method='lm', 
                          fullrange = T, se = F) +
              theme_bw() +
              ylim(0, 4.5) + 
              xlab('temperature °C')+
              ylab('Isoprene[ppb]') + 
              theme(legend.position = "top") +
              scale_color_hue(labels = c('February','March','April','May','June'))
```

And this is what I am getting. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to *"include a legend in my plot that shows the name of the months next to the line"*. That's what your plot already shows.

Comment: Not the answer to your question but I think you should use `geom_point` not `geom_jitter` as your x-axis variable is continuous, not discrete. And you probably need only `color` inside `aes()`, not `fill` as well. Also helpful to provide some or all of the data in `bio_all_data`, as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you need to add `scale_shape()` with the same labels.

The issue here is that you map one variable (month) to 3 aesthetics - color, shape and fill. That would give you one legend, but the addition of `scale_color_hue()` separates the mapping of color and shape.

To illustrate using a reproducible example - we will omit fill because only color is relevant to `geom_point`. This works as expected:

```
library(ggplot2)
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Species, shape = Species))
```

[image]

Now we add `scale_color_hue`. We get a separate legend because the labels differ to the default labels used when we mapped to shape:

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Species, shape = Species)) + 
  scale_color_hue(labels = LETTERS[1:3])
```

[image]

The simplest fix is to use the same labels in `scale_shape`. Alternatively you could `dplyr::mutate()` the data frame to add a column with month name and map to that instead.

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Species, shape = Species)) + 
  scale_color_hue(labels = LETTERS[1:3]) + 
  scale_shape(labels = LETTERS[1:3])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried scale_shape and got the legend with the desired shapes and colours but the black legend is still there. Any ideas? I already created a new variable to map as you suggested but I am intrigued.

Comment: I found the problem. the fill option was being also used to create a separate legend. I take it out. Cheers.